# Add a comment to Facebook Questions programmatically

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We can add a comment to a Facebook question via Facebook website. Also, We can programmatically add a question option to a Facebook question, However, is it possible to programmatically add a comment to a Question?

Comment: It's so ridiculous to not able to have the word, question, in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add a comment programmatically to a question which is already posted earlier in facebook. you cannot programmatically post a question and comment on it programmatically at the same time.